# Netbeans 7.0.1 with PHP 5 and SVN doesn't allow me to save

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using netbeans 7.0.1 with SVN PHP 5 project. My problem is that I've made changes in the file and when I try to save it (hitting CTRL+S) I hear the sound like "dimp" and it doesn't save the file. If I go to File->Save it is disabled.

I already know that if the file is already saved the Save option because disabled, but in this case my change is not saved yet as I close the file, open it again and the change is not there.

Any ideas how to solve it?
Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have the right permissions on the SVN repository, in that case you should do a "CHECKOUT" of the project to a local folder and edit the files from there.
Later on with the right credentials you can "COMMIT" your changes to the repository.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that...I did a checkout and changed the code locally, but somehow, I can't save the file locally (I already checked and the file is not read only)

Comment: Besides the file not being read only have you checked the filesystem rights where you store the files locally ?

Comment: Now, closing and opening again Netbeans let me save the file...strange...really strange...anyway...I'll mark your answer as correct as after that I thought about something wrong with the file.